# How do you make a while true loop continuedly check for a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, time

```
def main():
    from playsound import playsound as play
    import datetime
    time=datetime.datetime.now()
    hour=int(input("Hour of alarm: "))
    minute=int(input("Minute of alarm: "))
    #sound chooser
    alarm=str(input("Alarm, PI, AC, AV, BE, ZE, IO: "))
    noise=""
    #sound files
    if alarm== "PI":
        noise="8D_Pure_Imagination.mp3"
    elif alarm=="AC":
        noise="8D_chill2_noise.mp3"
    elif alarm=="AV":
        noise="8D_avatar_clip.mp3"
    elif alarm=="BE":
        noise="8D_Beach.mp3"
    elif alarm=="ZE":
        noise="8D_zelda_clip.mp3"
    elif alarm=="IO":
        noise="8D_iroh.mp3"
    #sound player

    while 1==1:
        if time.hour == hour and time.minute == minute:
           play(noise)
        else:
            if time.hour==hour and time.minute== minute:
                play(noise)
        
main()
```

The problem is it checks for the statement once and so it works if you play it at the exact same time, i want it to be opened, and set an alarm, then play a sound at that time, but after checking the if statement once, it stops.

Comment: Read your conditions. The `else` will never be executed because... It is the same as `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to recheck the time, you need to reinitialize `time = datetime.datetime.now()` at the end of every loop; otherwise, `time` is always the same.